# Intent launched from chrome is ignoring component

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking

In my app I have two activities that handle `myapp://some_task` uri.

When I create a button in html with the following link (per [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)):

```
intent://some_task#Intent;scheme=myapp;end
```

It displays a selector to the user asking which activity to use for that intent (makes sense).

So I've added a component part to the intent, so I can select which activity to use:

```
intent://some_task#Intent;scheme=myapp;component=com.package/.Activity1;end
```

But it just **ignores** the component part and still shows the activity selector

I've also tried with package+component, without the custom uri:

```
intent:#Intent;package=com.package;component=com.package/.Activity1;end
```

This one seems to always open the `Play Store` on my app's page.

I know I can change one of the activities to handle a different URL, but it'll take forever until all users update to the fixed version, and I need this to push a message with this intent to all users.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using explicit (full) component name, like this: `component=com.package/com.package.Activity1;` ?

Comment: yes, i've tried that too, didn't make a difference.